# Setting many to many relation from non owning side

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entity

I have 3 entities. viz A B C Enties A and B have one to one relation. Where as B and C has many to many relationship.

```
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
class A{
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private B b;

}


@Entity
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
class B{
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="b")
    @JoinTable(name ="C_B", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="B_id"), inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="C_id"))
    Set<C> C = new HashSet<C>();

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private A a;
}

@Entity
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
class C{
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name ="C_B", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="C_id"), inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="B_id"))
    Set<B> b = new HashSet<B>();

}
```

I create Entity for A and create entity B and set `a.setB(b)` and `b.setA(a)` and persist. It is saved in the table. But how to set the relation ship between B and C from B since it is not the owner?

I tried following

```
a.setB(b);
b.setA(a);
b.setC(c);
```

It is not creating any entry in the join table C_B.

And creating

```
a.setB(b);
b.setA(a);
b.setC(c);
c.setB(b);
```

throws null pointer exception.
Stack trace

```
2013-10-30 22:22:39,652 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-3:) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
2013-10-30 22:22:39,652 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-3:)   at org.hibernate.type.IntegerType.next(IntegerType.java:59) 
2013-10-30 22:22:39,652 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-3:)   at org.hibernate.engine.Versioning.increment(Versioning.java:108)
2013-10-30 22:22:39,652 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-3:)   at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.getNextVersion(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:365)
2013-10-30 22:22:39,652 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-3:)   at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.scheduleUpdate(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:257)
2013-10-30 22:22:39,652 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-3:)   at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:128)
2013-10-30 22:22:39,652 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-3:)   at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:196)
2013-10-30 22:22:39,652 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-3:)   at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:76)
2013-10-30 22:22:39,652 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-3:)   at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:26)
2013-10-30 22:22:39,652 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-3:)   at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
2013-10-30 22:22:39,652 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-3:)   at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:338)
2013-10-30 22:22:39,652 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-3:)   at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl$1.beforeCompletion(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:515)
2013-10-30 22:22:39,652 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-3:)   ... 77 more
```

How to establish relation between B and C

Setters looks like this

```
setB(B b){
        this.B.add(b);
    }

    setC(C c){
        this.C.add(c);
    }
```

Comment: where are `setA`, `setB` and `setC` defined?

Comment: I think from C instead of many-to-many you should use one-to-many

Comment: setB in Class A, setA and setC in Class B and setB in Class C

Comment: can you show what `setB` or `setC` method does?

Comment: @shikjohari I tried OneToMany relation too. But same result. It wont persist in the Join table.

Comment: @math i have edited the question with set method bodies

Comment: Are you sure that when you do `Set<B> b` and `a.setB(b);` you're not mistaking the `b` collection variable with the `b` object reference variable? It would be safer if you rename the `b` collection variable to another name, say `manyBs`

Comment: Nope. I am adding them in the collection properly.

Comment: Please post your exception stack trace.

Comment: Can you post the fill code of Entity C? Looks like the you have an @Version field which is not initialized correctly.

Comment: Hi Alan, It was the problem with the version. I have corrected it and it is working fine